# Is this supposition on laplace transforms mathematically sound?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

$$\mathcal{L}(tf(t)) = -\dfrac {dF(s)}{ds}$$
If $y'' - 4y = 4H(t-2)$ then
$$\mathcal {L}(4tH(t-2)) =-\dfrac {d(\mathcal {L}(y''- 4y))}{ds}$$

If there is a fault in this line of reasoning how could one solve this problem. Given that $y(0) = 0$ and $y''(0) = \sinh(-2)$

Comment: What is $H$? Without further definition one would suspect the Heaviside or unit ramp function. Where does the construct $tf(t)$ come from?

Comment: Yes, it is the Heaviside function. I multiplied it by t in order to have the derivative of F(s) on the right. Is that a reasonable way to solve this problem? Please let me know the correct method

Comment: Why not just take the Laplace transform of both sides, $Y(s)(s^2-4)=\frac{e^{2s}}{s}$? Then apply partial fractions and transform back.

Comment: That's the correct approach it seems. I overcomplicated it. Thanks for the reply